# 18 digit field truncating

Tags: sql, mysql, numbers, numeric, long-integer

i have an account number that is 18 digits - when i try to extract the field to CSV it truncates the number (zeroing out last digits) how can i format this field so it doesnt truncate?

what i currently have:
(LEFT(Pr.Account_Number__c, 18)

Comment: How are you viewing the CSV? Excel <> CSV. Open in a text editor such as Notepad++ and you'll probably see it's not truncating.

Comment: If you are viewing in Excel, you might be interested in the following tips (particularly the bit under "Credit card numbers are rounded down"): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keeping-leading-zeros-and-large-numbers-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7

Comment: This is an Excel problem, not MySQL.

Comment: Please post sample CSV output and provide DDL (that works on dbfiddle.uk) to demonstrate the input.